# Symlink with CakePHP

Tags: linux, apache, cakephp, ubuntu, symlink

i have a problem with Symlinks.
My website: www.mysite.com is directed to:

> /httpdocs/cakephp/app

In the same httpdocs I have another folder:

> /httpdocs/resources

Now... i created a symlink called resources (from httpdocs/resources) into httpdocs/cakephp/app/webroot. This symlink is working okay. The problem is that when I try to access the symlink from the browser, I get: Forbidden 403.

This are the permissions of the symlink:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root          root     47 2013-11-20 05:18 resources -> /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/resources
```

I'm running: Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of research I founded the problem, just add this line in the top of your .htdocs files of CakePHP:

> Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI